# How make single page for WP_List_Table edit?

Tags: wordpress

How I can create admin page, to edit single item from custom table `WP_List_Table`?

Data: Custom DB Table, on admin I have add menu item with method which build this table through `WP_List_Table`.

There I want to create 'manage' button, to manage single item from this table.

How  can I do this?

- Is there some action hook
- or i have to just add second class
- Or like menu item

I have try add like menu item, But how  can I add it without adding to the menu? `add_submenu_page` with parent `slug = null` is it really clear WP solution?

Comment: We are not here to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my situation good solution:

```
if ( array_key_exists( 'single', $_REQUEST ) ) {
    //function to process single item
} else {
    //Create an instance of our package class...
    $withdraw = new Class_Table();
    //Fetch, prepare, sort, and filter our data...
    $withdraw->prepare_items();
}
```